# Azure DevOps Remove a security group from All Repositories settings using Azure CLI or Rest API

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-repos

**Question** : How can I remove a security group from All repositories settings in a project using azure cli or rest API. In this case I would like to remove the Contributors group.

[image]

I was able to add a security group and give permissions using

```
#Get the security group descriptor . 
$subject = az devops security group list `
    --org "https://dev.azure.com/$orgname/" `
    --project "$prjname" `
    --subject-types vssgp `
    --query "graphGroups[?@.principalName == $groupName.descriptor | [0]"

        #Update the security permission by passing the namespace ID bit and Subject 
    az devops security permission update `
        --org "https://dev.azure.com/$orgname/" `
        --id $namespaceId `
        --subject $subject `
        --token "repoV2/$projectid" `
        --allow-bit $PermissionBit `
        --merge true
```

Any suggestions or idea would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I just deployed the test project **SmartHotel360** by the [Azure Devops Demo Generator](https://azuredevopsdemogenerator.azurewebsites.net/environment/createproject) in order to get a sandbox and as per [az devops security group list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/security/group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-devops-security-group-list), running:

```
az devops security group list --project <project-name> --output table --organization=<https://dev.azure.com/MyOrganization/>
```

you can list all the groups in a project or organization.

Running the above command, I got:

```
Name                             Descriptor
-------------------------------  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[test2]\Release Administrators   vssgp.Uy0xLTktMTU1MTM3NDI0NS0xNDI0MjY5MTEwLTQwOTM0Njc5NjktMzEzNjU3ODA0NS00MDk1MTIxOTEzLTEtMzc1OTU4MjU2NS0zNzIxNDI5MTgtMjc0MTM0MTg3Mi00MDk0NzU2NjE3
[test2]\Project Valid Users      vssgp.Uy0xLTktMTU1MTM3NDI0NS02NjQ0MjExMDAtODcyMjM4NjcxLTI3NjQxMDc4MDYtMzQyOTQ4NzY4Ni0wLTAtMC0wLTM
[test2]\Endpoint Creators        vssgp.Uy0xLTktMTU1MTM3NDI0NS02NjQ0MjExMDAtODcyMjM4NjcxLTI3NjQxMDc4MDYtMzQyOTQ4NzY4Ni0wLTAtMC04LTk
[test2]\test2 Team               vssgp.Uy0xLTktMTU1MTM3NDI0NS0xNDI0MjY5MTEwLTQwOTM0Njc5NjktMzEzNjU3ODA0NS00MDk1MTIxOTEzLTEtMzUwMDk0MjcwLTIzMTAxMjIwNTYtMjgyMjA0OTAwOS0xMzA4MDY5ODYy
[test2]\Readers                  vssgp.Uy0xLTktMTU1MTM3NDI0NS0xNDI0MjY5MTEwLTQwOTM0Njc5NjktMzEzNjU3ODA0NS00MDk1MTIxOTEzLTEtNDA5MjE5NTkzNC0yMTEzNzE5MTA0LTMxOTA3OTkyOTctMzU4OTYxOTI5OQ
[test2]\Endpoint Administrators  vssgp.Uy0xLTktMTU1MTM3NDI0NS02NjQ0MjExMDAtODcyMjM4NjcxLTI3NjQxMDc4MDYtMzQyOTQ4NzY4Ni0wLTAtMC04LTg
[test2]\Contributors             vssgp.Uy0xLTktMTU1MTM3NDI0NS0xNDI0MjY5MTEwLTQwOTM0Njc5NjktMzEzNjU3ODA0NS00MDk1MTIxOTEzLTEtMzU5NDE1MjA0OC0zMzg4NzA3NDAyLTI4Mzc1ODU2MjQtMzA4NDgwODg5Mg
[test2]\Build Administrators     vssgp.Uy0xLTktMTU1MTM3NDI0NS02NjQ0MjExMDAtODcyMjM4NjcxLTI3NjQxMDc4MDYtMzQyOTQ4NzY4Ni0wLTAtMC0xLTI
[test2]\Project Administrators   vssgp.Uy0xLTktMTU1MTM3NDI0NS02NjQ0MjExMDAtODcyMjM4NjcxLTI3NjQxMDc4MDYtMzQyOTQ4NzY4Ni0wLTAtMC0wLTE
[test2]\Web                      vssgp.Uy0xLTktMTU1MTM3NDI0NS0xNDI0MjY5MTEwLTQwOTM0Njc5NjktMzEzNjU3ODA0NS00MDk1MTIxOTEzLTEtMTE0OTE2NjA5MC0xMjA0MTE5ODgxLTIyMjI5MjAxOTItNTQ2NTIzMTY3
[test2]\Mobile                   vssgp.Uy0xLTktMTU1MTM3NDI0NS0xNDI0MjY5MTEwLTQwOTM0Njc5NjktMzEzNjU3ODA0NS00MDk1MTIxOTEzLTEtMjQzNTg5NTk1Ni0zNDk0MTc5OTExLTI0MjQxODg2MDQtNDEwNDg1MDUzNA
```

If we have to delete the **[test2]\Contributors**, we need to run the following command:

```
az devops security group delete --id <Descriptor> --organization=<https://dev.azure.com/MyOrganization/>
```

getting the double check by Microsoft regarding the action:

```
Are you sure you want to delete this group? (y/n): y
```

Once replied with **y**, re-running the *list* command, I got:

```
Name                             Descriptor
-------------------------------  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[test2]\Release Administrators   vssgp.Uy0xLTktMTU1MTM3NDI0NS0xNDI0MjY5MTEwLTQwOTM0Njc5NjktMzEzNjU3ODA0NS00MDk1MTIxOTEzLTEtMzc1OTU4MjU2NS0zNzIxNDI5MTgtMjc0MTM0MTg3Mi00MDk0NzU2NjE3
[test2]\Project Valid Users      vssgp.Uy0xLTktMTU1MTM3NDI0NS02NjQ0MjExMDAtODcyMjM4NjcxLTI3NjQxMDc4MDYtMzQyOTQ4NzY4Ni0wLTAtMC0wLTM
[test2]\Endpoint Creators        vssgp.Uy0xLTktMTU1MTM3NDI0NS02NjQ0MjExMDAtODcyMjM4NjcxLTI3NjQxMDc4MDYtMzQyOTQ4NzY4Ni0wLTAtMC04LTk
[test2]\test2 Team               vssgp.Uy0xLTktMTU1MTM3NDI0NS0xNDI0MjY5MTEwLTQwOTM0Njc5NjktMzEzNjU3ODA0NS00MDk1MTIxOTEzLTEtMzUwMDk0MjcwLTIzMTAxMjIwNTYtMjgyMjA0OTAwOS0xMzA4MDY5ODYy
[test2]\Readers                  vssgp.Uy0xLTktMTU1MTM3NDI0NS0xNDI0MjY5MTEwLTQwOTM0Njc5NjktMzEzNjU3ODA0NS00MDk1MTIxOTEzLTEtNDA5MjE5NTkzNC0yMTEzNzE5MTA0LTMxOTA3OTkyOTctMzU4OTYxOTI5OQ
[test2]\Endpoint Administrators  vssgp.Uy0xLTktMTU1MTM3NDI0NS02NjQ0MjExMDAtODcyMjM4NjcxLTI3NjQxMDc4MDYtMzQyOTQ4NzY4Ni0wLTAtMC04LTg
[test2]\Build Administrators     vssgp.Uy0xLTktMTU1MTM3NDI0NS02NjQ0MjExMDAtODcyMjM4NjcxLTI3NjQxMDc4MDYtMzQyOTQ4NzY4Ni0wLTAtMC0xLTI
[test2]\Project Administrators   vssgp.Uy0xLTktMTU1MTM3NDI0NS02NjQ0MjExMDAtODcyMjM4NjcxLTI3NjQxMDc4MDYtMzQyOTQ4NzY4Ni0wLTAtMC0wLTE
[test2]\Web                      vssgp.Uy0xLTktMTU1MTM3NDI0NS0xNDI0MjY5MTEwLTQwOTM0Njc5NjktMzEzNjU3ODA0NS00MDk1MTIxOTEzLTEtMTE0OTE2NjA5MC0xMjA0MTE5ODgxLTIyMjI5MjAxOTItNTQ2NTIzMTY3
[test2]\Mobile                   vssgp.Uy0xLTktMTU1MTM3NDI0NS0xNDI0MjY5MTEwLTQwOTM0Njc5NjktMzEzNjU3ODA0NS00MDk1MTIxOTEzLTEtMjQzNTg5NTk1Ni0zNDk0MTc5OTExLTI0MjQxODg2MDQtNDEwNDg1MDUzNA
```

stating **[test2]\Contributors** has been correctly deleted.

I got the same result verifying it from the GUI:
[image]

Please, be sure to delete the correct security group!
I strongly recommend to try those commands in a sandbox first, maybe on a test environment deployed by the Azure Devops Demo Generator.

Hoping it helps.

Comment: Hi Nico, thank you for the answer. I am having a little difficulty with above command. When I run az ad group show , I can see the security group , in this case "Contributors" and the JSON response for each item has some of the keys as originId , principal name but I dont find  objectId . Might the security group you are suggesting is Active Directory group , where as I am asking about the Azure DevOps Security group. Also can you tell what does a8bb6c46-6d7a-4e2f-8b86-1b685b613c6a mean ?

Comment: Hi Joe, serious apologies, I copied and pasted the previous commands following some old notes but checking directly on the Microsoft site, something has changed. I re-wrote the entire answer, full of explanations.

Comment: Hi Nico, thank you for getting back, If I understand correctly , you are deleting the security group which in turn will remove across the PROJECT , am I correct ? If so , I dont want that behaviour, I just want to remove it from All repositories -> security tab. I still want the contributors group to be available in the project so that users of Contributors security group can access boards and pipelines. Hope this makes sense..

Comment: got it Joe! For my understanding, we cannot remove "Contributors" from all the repositories only.
What about denying everything on them? This action can be done directly on "Project Settings -> All Repositories -> Contributors" via GUI or (I think...) applying an Azure policy via a json file